# Animating line on the canvas by increasing the value on the lineTo parameters

Tags: javascript

i am trying to animate a line on a canvas, to the top of the screen. So the line is going to move vertically . i used object to create a new line, the added two methods, 1 to draw the line and the other to update the moveTo y parameter and lineTo y parameter.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function random(min, max) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
}

function Line( mtX, mtY, ltX, ltY, ltVX, mtVY, color, exists){
    this.mtX = mtX;
    this.mtY = mtY;
    this.ltX = ltX;
    this.ltY = ltY;
    this.mtVY = mtVY;
    this.ltVX = ltVX;
    this.color = color;
    this.exists = exists
 }

 Line.prototype.draw = function(){
ctx.beginPath(); 
// Staring point (0,550)
ctx.moveTo(this.mtX, this.mtY);
console.log(this.mtY)
// End point (300, 550)
ctx.lineTo(this.ltX, this.ltY);
// Set the line color
ctx.strokeStyle = this.color
// Make the line visible
ctx.stroke();
}



Line.prototype.update = function(){

  if(this.mtY <= 0 || this.ltY <= 0){
  this.exists = false
  }
  this.mtY -= this.mtVY
  this.ltY -= this.ltVX
}
let testLine = new Line(0, 550, 300, 550, 29, 29, 'green', true)
 function loop(){
if(testLine.exists){
    testLine.update();
    testLine.draw();

} 
requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
loop();
```

instead of moving a single line created, the animation is creating a new lines on each  animation  loop